# #mrtk Accessing Hololens Spatial Map MRTK v2

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I have been having trouble trying to understand how to use the Spatial Awareness user guide for the latest MRTK release to get access to the spatial mapping meshes to use in a multi-user app. I cannot find a way to serialize the meshes to be able to send them to a remote device as was previously possible in the older toolkit. I have tried to add the meshes to a list and used the old simplemeshserializer but that did not seem to work at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated in trying to understand the current capabilities in current MRTK and how the same functionality can be replicated.

Comment: I think it'd be more helpful if you could share what you've already done (screenshots/source code), so it maybe easier to understand the problem for others.

Comment: I have followed the usage guide here: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/SpatialAwareness/UsageGuide.html.  Under the Enumerating and accessing the meshes, I have tried to take the mesh objects and create a list of meshes that can be serialized to then send to a remote device using webrtc data channel.  I have been trying to replicate the capability that was in HTK to send spatial maps from hololens to remote device but once I send the list the remote device becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing problems with mrtk v2 spatial awareness too. Have you tried using surface types? I couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: Haven’t tried surface types since it would not help with what I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to transfer the mesh between multiple devices, but when you use the simplemeshserializer to serialize the mesh in MRTKv2 and transfer it, the remote device becomes unresponsive?

According to some previous cares of transferring mesh between multiple clients, we hope that you can follow the steps below to troubleshoot:

1. Is data received correctly when transferring data using WebRTC?
2. Is the data still reliable after deserialization? You can try to save it locally and verify it.
3. After receiving the data and deserializing it, how did you handle these deserialized meshes?  Can you provide the small sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Using the example I commented on previously, I added to it as such:  foreach (SpatialAwarenessMeshObject meshObject in observer.Meshes.Values)
   {
    mesh = meshObject.Filter.mesh;
    List<Mesh> meshesToSend = new List<Mesh>();
    meshesToSend.Add(mesh);
    byte[] serializedMeshes = SimpleMeshSerializer.Serialize(meshesToSend);
    peerConnection._meshDataChannel.SendMessage(serializedMeshes);

   }

Comment: @AristidesStaikos it is difficult for us to find the cause of the problem based on the code snippet. So it is recommended that you follow the steps in the anwser to troubleshoot. This will help us locate the issue.